# the select attribute in xsl:apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to get back into XSL/XSLT after many years and need some help to understand some XSL that I have received as an example. The TEI-based XML file that I would like to transform, has the following schematic structure:

```
<text>
 <body>
  <div>
   <div type="text">
    <ab>
     <lg type="text-de">
      <l>TEXT</l>
      ...
     </lg>
    </ab>
   </div>
   <div type="text">
    <ab>
     <lg type="text-en">
      <l>TEXT</l>
      ...
     </lg>
    </ab>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</text>
```

I have a snippet of XSL that I would like to use to transform the above file. The XSL that I have looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:div">
  SOME HTML CODE
  <div class="text-de">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:lg[(@type='text-de')]"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-en">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:lg[(@type='text-en')]"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I think the expected HTML output is clear, but please let me know if you need me to explain anything. What I am trying to achieve is that the two different blocks of text get inserted into two different  elements in various places of the resulting HTML. However, when I run the above XSLT no block of text is selected. I would be grateful for any explanations that make me understand the nature of the select attribute in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lg` elements are not processed because they are not child nodes of the `div` element, rwther they sit inside of `ab` element. So you need to select `ab/lg` respectively with the proper namespace prefix which is `<xsl:apply-templates select="tei:ab/tei:lg[@type='text-de']"/>`.

Here is a more complete example, with the input XML being

```
<text xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
 <body>
  <div>
   <div type="text">
    <ab>
     <lg type="text-de">
      <l>TEXT</l>
      ...
     </lg>
    </ab>
   </div>
   <div type="text">
    <ab>
     <lg type="text-en">
      <l>TEXT</l>
      ...
     </lg>
    </ab>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</text>
```

and the XSLT being

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="tei">


<xsl:template match="tei:div[@type = 'text']">
  SOME HTML CODE
  <div class="text-de">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:ab/tei:lg[@type='text-de']"/>
  </div>
  <div class="text-en">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:ab/tei:lg[@type='text-en']"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
  SOME HTML CODE
  <div class="text-de">
      TEXT
      ...
     </div><div class="text-en"/>

  SOME HTML CODE
  <div class="text-de"/><div class="text-en">
      TEXT
      ...
     </div>
```

So with the right match patterns and paths the elements are processed. I am sure the result is not the final one you want but you need to add more templates to get a clean transformation to HTML. If you still have problems then post a new question or edit the existing one, showing the result sample you want.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing happens in the output, when I change `select="tei:lg[(@type='text-de')]` to `select="tei:ab/lg[(@type='text-de')]` or `select="tei:div/ab/lg[(@type='text-de')]`. What am I missing? Could the problem be caused by the wrong value in @match?

Comment: Well you need to use the prefix consistently, I have edited my answer. Next time, please, if namespaces are used in the input XML, then present a sample including those namespaces.

Comment: Thanks again. I was convinced that this was not a namespace issue and omitted that information. My apologies. The XML uses the TEI namespace `<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">`, and the XSL starts like this: `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`
But still no luck, even after editing the XSL according to your example. Could this possibly have to do with the transformer? I am using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.5 in oXygen.

Comment: I overlooked that the `div` elements are nested as well. I will edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I did trim down the XML to contain only one `<div>` element. The rest of what I need will be done by some CSS. I marked your reply as the answer, but am unable to vote up, as I am a newbie with little privileges.